# Problems with rebinding model to a list the second time in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am new to Ember and I am trying to make a simple demo app where a list gets rerendered with differrent data when a button is pressed.

Here is a running example of my attempt, by pressing SHOW LIST button a tweet list is shown, and the binding works fine for the first time: http://jsfiddle.net/0xnpav6L/21/

Below are the two places in the code where I've tried to rebind the model to the list:

1)in ApplicationController - I tried to bind the bindNewModel action to the MODIFY button, but it doesn't seem to be working.

2)in ListController - tried to bind bindNewModel action to all the list items(when any list item is pressed), but also that does not seem to work.

```
    App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
            actions: {
                bindNewModel: function() {
                    console.log(App.ListController);
                    this.set('model', renderTweets());
                }
            }
        });

    App.ListController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
            init: function() {
                this.set('model', renderTweets());
            },
            actions: {
                bindNewModel: function() {
                    this.set('model', renderTweets());
                }
            }
        });
```

Any help would be appreaciated.

Comment: If your new to ember why are you using ember `1.8`? A lot of patterns you're using are removed/deprecated in the latest ember version which is `2.12`.

Comment: nope you haven't. This is still `1.8`. Check the resources panel. Your code wouldn't even run with `2.12`. Things like `ArrayController` are removed from ember since `2.0`. Also notice that your link to `2.12` is not valid. Your entire code is build on outdated examples/tutorials. Checkout `ember-cli`, the guides for the latest ember version, `ember-twiddle` instead of the fiddle and maybe join the slack channel [for help. Here you can find a link.](https://emberjs.com/community/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lux is absolutely right with his comments; you are using quite an old version; and I suggest using [ember twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/) for demonstrating your ember trials.

Anyway; regarding your code the model at your `Application.Controller` is not related with what is rendered at `#/list`. Hence, I only made some modifications to `ListController` in order to update content when an item is clicked. I set `model.data` instead of `model` itself and in handlebars i used `{{#each model in this.model.data}}` so that it iterates over model's data attribute. Please check the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k1nLqr2w/) to see at least it updates properly.

Yet again, it should be much better for you if you read [official Ember Guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/) and get started with Ember's current version `2.12.0`.